# MKDIR (wp_mkdir_p) with "-" comes out strange

Tags: php

Using MKDIR

> `File Name Test – () _ <>`

However the folder that is created it:

> `File Name Test &#8211; () _ <>`

Evidently the "-" seems to cause an issue.

The code

Here are the cars I am using as well:

```
$web_video_location = get_the_title();
$category = get_the_category();
$catname = $category[0]->cat_name;

if (wp_mkdir_p('./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/'.$catname."/".$web_video_location)) {
  echo "";
}
```

I am not quite sure what I am missing. The folder is created on a webserver.

**update**

If I make a WP title, such as:

```
File Name Test-() _ <>
```

It make a folder:

```
File Name Test-() _ <>
```

it appears it is something to do with the spaces.

**Update**

I also tried this:

```
$mkdir_cat = "$webdir$catname";
$mkdir_file = "$mkdir_cat/$web_video_location";


if (wp_mkdir_p( $mkdir_file )) {
  echo "";
}
```

Still not joy. I think this is a little over my head.

If the cat has a `-` it works? I do not get it.

Comment: The "-" looks HTML encoded.

Comment: I have tried is like this :'if (wp_mkdir_p("'./wp-content/uploads/webvideos/'.$catname."/".$web_video_location")) {
  echo "";
}'    - So I am not quite sure. I have tired various combinations.

Comment: Are you 2000% sure you're actually using the character "–" and not `&#8211;`?! How are you confirming?

Comment: [There's no trace of HTML entity encoding in the `wp_mkdir_p` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L1468), so the problem is probably with `$web_video_location` or `$catname`. You could probably [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) them.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the tile from wordpress which is `File Name Test - () _ <>`  I have included the `$web_video_location` and `$catname`.

Comment: Bear in mind that debugging HTML encoding can be very tricky if what you're using to debug with is a browser - you need to be *very* careful that the `&#8211;` is part of the filename, not an escape applied by the output function; and conversely that the `-` you copied and pasted isn't your browser's rendering of `&#8211;`.

Comment: @IMSoP No, only when making the folder on the webserver. When I look at the title of the post it is `File Name Test - () _ <>`.

Comment: @Arthor But where are you looking at the title?

Comment: @IMSoP Via word press front end and the back end.

Comment: @Arthor Right, so you are looking at it through a browser...

Comment: Yes, but the PHP execution is backend, so I am not sure why it would add that part. Even more so. If I make a new post with the name ` this is a test - yes - it - is'. the problem occurs however not with a category with the same browser.

Comment: Ok. I have tries with this '–' and it work. But I do not understand. I am using my keyboard? So..... what is going on? Google chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is WordPress trying to be helpful - the [`wptexturize` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize) is automatically run all over the place, including in the filter `the_title` applied by `the_title()`/`get_the_title()`. It does various "smart" transforms, including turning `-` (space hyphen space) into `–` (en-dash).

However, it does this by emitting HTML entities like `&#8211;`. This is not so useful when you are trying to use content for something other than HTML display.

I can think of a few workarounds:

- allow WordPress to format the dash, then unescape it with [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode), e.g. `$web_video_location = html_entity_decode(get_the_title());`
- disable `wptexturize` globally, e.g. using [`run_wptexturize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/), so it leaves your titles alone
- grab the title a different way, e.g. accessing `$post->post_title` directly; you can see [the source of the `get_the_title` function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L98) for some hints on how
- use something other than the title as the filename, e.g. a [Custom Field](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) on the post

Comment: PERFECT. I used the first option. This is good to know for the future. Thank you